# What do I do if my puppy's worms burrow into the floor!

Tags: dogs

I own 2 dogs, one of them have worms (2 months) while the other doesn't (7 years). I was completely shocked when I saw worms going into my floor! If my other dog (no worms) walk into an area where the worms burrowed into, is he going to be okay? Or will the worms go somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it depends on the type of worms that your dog has. Dogs can be infected with a variety of species of worms, with different lifecycles. Some worms can only be transmitted through an intermediate host, such as a mosquito. Some worms lay eggs which are passed in the dog's stool, and can then be ingested by another dog. Some worms enter through openings in the skin.

This [article](http://www.peteducation.com/article.cfm?c=2&aid=757) contains more information.